# Why use LFSR on this context?

Tags: fpga, lfsr

There is a task in Pong chu's fpga prototyping book which is to basically generate a random number from 0 to 15_000 millisecond. I saw someone's [code  who used LFSR](https://github.com/barbedo/verilog-book/blob/master/chapter6/6.5.6_reaction_timer/src/design/lfsr_pseudo_random.v). (ctto owner)

The author used a free-running counter and when the "start" button is pressed, the value of the counter at that moment will be used as the seed to the LFSR(linear feedback shift register). But I don't understand the need of the LFSR if the number of times that LFSR will be shifted is fixed (shift_count_next = 6'd14 @line69) ,**meaning a specific counter value will HAVE A FIXED LFSR value** which I believe is a round-about way of generating a random number. So I thought, why not just use the value of the free-running counter itself as the random number?

But am I missing something? Why use LFSR on this context if the number of times it will be shifted is fixed?

Comment: Is the 14 bit counter started or read randomly?

Comment: I guess because the numbers might all be the same? If you count milliseconds and you press the start button after 2 seconds, all your random numbers would be 2xxx

Comment: If you have sync’d reads there may be aliasing bias for certain numbers. I.e. not enough entropy.

Comment: Apple ][‘s RAND() was so poor , we had to use the time + date to reseed it constantly to map a QVGA display of 38k sectors to pixels of a 5+5MB HDD

Comment: 14-bit runner is read randomly(depends on when user presses the button)

Answer (score 3):

If it isn't important to have true randomness, an LFSR is one of the easiest ways to produce pseudorandom numbers. The output appears to have little relation to the seed value.

In this case, using that free running counter directly might appear insufficiently random, depending on how long the counter is and how fast the clock is. If a counter value of, say, 100000 gives a timer length of 1000 ms, and a counter value of 101000 gives 1010 ms, it's easy to see a relationship between the time you hit the button and the time of the delay. Running it through an LFSR for a few iterations, even if the number of iterations is fixed, serves to essentially "scramble" the input, so that a counter value of 100 may give a delay of 8189 ms, while a counter of 101 may give a delay of 397 ms.

With a fixed number of iterations, the LFSR *could* be replaced with a lookup table, but keeping the LFSR is probably more space-efficient as the LUT would have to be quite large assuming the counter has at least as many bits as the output timer.

Comment: Ahh yes makes sense, if I'm  fast enough then the random number will appear to be ascending....

Answer (score 1):

If you use the timer counter directly, then "random" values that are produced near each other in time will be highly correlated. Using an LFSR basically serves as whitening — the values you get out of the LFSR even just a few time steps apart will look very different.

Answer (score 1):

If you only use the counter a few times, that’s random enough, for 1/f << human response time to some reference time.

But if this is read synchronously afterwords with the derived clock, then it won’t be random.

Comment: My clk is 50MHz so 15_000 turns will take 0.3ms, hmmm so I think it's good enough for me....